# well-posedness of Navier - Stokes in exterior domains

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

Assume we have a two dimensional, incompressible fluid and a moving body (translating and rotating) inside the fluid. The exterior boundary in at infinity (open flow). Then the Navier-Stokes equations  are written as

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\displaystyle
\frac{D\mathbf{u}}{Dt}=\displaystyle-\frac{\nabla p}{\rho_0} + \nu \nabla^2\mathbf{u} , \quad in \quad D\times(0,T), \label{momentum-eq}\\ \displaystyle
\nabla\cdot \mathbf{u}=\displaystyle 0,  \quad in \quad D\times(0,T),
\end{array}
\right. 
\\[0.5cm]\displaystyle
\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x},0)=\mathbf{u}_0(\mathbf{x}), \qquad\mbox{in } D,      \\ \displaystyle
\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x}_b)=\mathbf{u}_b , \quad on \quad {\partial D_B}\times(0,T), \nonumber     \\ \displaystyle
\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x}) \rightarrow\mathbf{u}_{\infty}(t), \quad as \quad |\mathbf{x}|\rightarrow\infty, \\ \displaystyle
  p \rightarrow p_{\infty}(t),  \;\quad as \quad |\mathbf{x}|\rightarrow\infty, 
\end{array}
\end{equation}

where in the momentum equation $\mathbf{u}$ is the velocity, $p$ is the pressure, $\rho_0$ is the density, $\nu$ is the kinematic viscosity of the specific fluid considered and $\mathbf{u}_b$ is the velocity of the body at $\mathbf{x}_b$ with $\mathbf{u}_b$ given. The problem boundary condition is the no-slip on the body boundary  with conditions at infinity for the pressure and  the velocity: $\mathbf{u}_\infty$ and $ p_{\infty}$  respectively.

I would like to ask is if there are any references on this problem. 
I have looked around a bit but without succeeding in finding anything on this specific problem.
I am interested also in the vorticity formulation.
Thank you very much.

Comment: You didn't write what $D$ is, I guess $D = \mathbb R^2 \setminus D_B$?

Comment: And I believe $u_b$ is a given function? If the rotation and translation speeds is constant, then there is this paper http://www.aimsciences.org/article/doi/10.3934/dcds.2018145

Comment: @CalvinKhor Yes, the domain D is exactly what you wrote. Also the velocity $\mathbf{u}_b$ is indeed given. It might be not constant though but let's let it be like that for simplicity. Thank you very much for the article. It seems to be very to the point. I will read it.